# How to find the middle element in linked list

Tags: c#, .net, oop, data-structures

I need a detailed algorithm , in c# about how to find the middle element in linked List.
I had checked google and all are talking about the two pointers which moves in parallel over the list . 
but actually , i couldn't find a detailed solution for the algorithm . and how these two pointers should be implemented .

i need the best solution regarding the performance .

Comment: In a double linked list just work from the start and the end until they meet.  In a single linked list just work one variable that moves through the list one item at a time and a second that moves two at a time.  When the second gets to the end the first should be at the middle.

Comment: What do you define as the "middle element" when there are an even number of elements in the list (eg if the are six elements is it the 3rd element - which has two preceding & 3 following - or the fourth which has 3 preceding & 2 following elements) ?

Comment: The problem is really stupid. In doubly or singly linked list you just add `int Count` property and then do Count/2 iterations from head. People who ask such questions on interviews are usually stupid too. Doing this the way i suggested gives you O(N/2) performance and compared to 2-iterators approach for doubly-linked list will cost you twice less CPU cycles.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty much what `juharr` suggested you in the comment for singly-linked list.

`GetMiddle` starts at head of the list, `rightPointer` looks two elements ahead, `leftPointer` looks at the next element (both pointers move in the same direction). In the end, when there are no more elements to examine, `leftPointer` is the middle node of the list.

In the code below `Node` is a singly-linked list node, and `List` just adds elements to the list and exposes its `head`.

```
public T GetMiddle<T>(List<T> list)
{
    Node<T> leftPointer = list.Head;
    Node<T> rightPointer = list.Head;

    while (rightPointer != null && rightPointer.Next != null)
    {
        rightPointer = rightPointer.Next.Next;
        leftPointer = leftPointer.Next;
    }

    return leftPointer.Item;
}

public class List<T>
{
    public Node<T> Head { get; private set; }
    private Node<T> Last;

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        Node<T> oldLast = Last;
        Last = new Node<T>(value);

        if (Head == null)
        {
            Head = Last;
        }
        else
        {
            oldLast.Next = Last;
        }
    }
}

public class Node<T>
{
    public T Item { get; private set; }
    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }

    public Node(T item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }
}
```

In case of even number of elements, like `[1, 9]`

```
var list = new List<int>();
foreach (var number in  Enumerable.Range(1, 9))
{
    list.Add(number);
}

Console.WriteLine(GetMiddle(list));
```

the middle element is `5`.

However, in case of even number of elements, line `[1, 10]`, algorithm will produce `6`. That is because when `right` is at `9`, it's next is not `null` but `10`. So when we finish this iteration, `right` is pointing to `null` and `left` is pointing at `6` (which we return as middle).

```
right: 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 7 -> 9 -> null | end
left:  1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6    | end
```

This means that in even case, you need to decide which element to take as middle - 5 or 6. If you want 5, you will need an extra condition in the loop:

```
rightPointer = rightPointer.Next.Next;        
if (rightPointer != null)
{
    leftPointer = leftPointer.Next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to finding the middle element with respect to performance is to just compute it:

```
var mid = list[list.Length/2];
```

This returns the element after the middle when `list.Length` is even.

If you want to return the element before the middle when `list.Length` is even, you can reduce and truncate:

```
var mid = list[(int)((list.Length-0.5)/2)];
```

Answer (score -1):

A Java solution for the above will be:

```
public ListNode middleNode(ListNode head) {
    if(head == null || head.next == null) { return head; }
    ListNode slow = head;
    ListNode fast = head;

    while(fast != null && fast.next != null) {
        slow = slow.next;
        fast = fast.next.next;
    }

    return slow;
}
```

A Node here is:

```
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}
```